# how to retrieve two or more column names based with a column values in oracle11g

Tags: oracle

I have a table like below

```
a   b   c   d   e   
0   1   0   1   1   b
1   0   0   1   0   a
```

Whereas I need  >0 column values header name like below

```
a   b   c   d   e   
0   1   0   1   1   b,d,e
1   0   0   1   0   a,d
```

Comment: ok did you try anything?  this is not a code writing services we answer questions.  You want code writing hire a consultant.

Comment: yea, i tried , but this is simplest form of my table for understand

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: This is going to be something ugly like: `CONCAT(CASE WHEN a>0 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END, CASE WHEN b>0 THEN 'B' ELSE '' END, CASE WHEN c>0 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END, CASE WHEN d>0 THEN 'D' ELSE '' END, CASE WHEN e>0 THEN 'E' ELSE '' END)` Although, it feels like maybe your schema isn't the best which is why this is so ugly to write out and requires editing to add new "headers" to it.

Comment: @JNevill -- that is an answer not a comment.  It is also wrong, his requirement shows `,` between each column name.  (hint -- put a comma after every name and then remove the trailing comma.)

Comment: Fully aware @Hogan. It's a direction for OP to explore. Perhaps if OP improves their question or shows a bit of effort, then I will improve my answer and try a little harder myself.